# sqlite join virtual table

Tags: ios, sqlite, full-text-search

I am woking on sqlite, I am not able to join two virtual tables. I am using Following query to join the table, but it is returing empty records.

select provFName from xp_messages_recepient  LEFT JOIN all_provider  on recepientUserId=providerID WHERE xpMessageId='1'

Let me know,

1: Is this allowed?
2: If it is allowed, what wrong I am doing there?

Comment: Your syntax looks correct to me (not knowing your particular database, of course.) I further assume that the typo recepientUserId/recipientUserID is only in your stackOverflow insertion and not in your actual SQL, correct?

Can you do the selects independently of the join to test that the data is there to join on?
Do your where clause work in a select on both tables?  Do you have matching IDs on both tables?

Comment: I have checked there is no typo, Only I used data type as integer. Will this affect?

Comment: We probably cannot help you further without seeing code. Are you checking all of the return codes from all of the SQLite functions to make sure you're getting `SQLITE_OK`? And where you're not, are you checking `sqlite3_errmsg`?

Comment: I got the problem, it is because of type casting of value while inserting.
Thanks you for showing interest.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It is because of typecasting issue. even if both the caoulm are integer it is representing valuse as text and integer. I resolved this by proper conversion before inserting values.